# Get device accounts from Flex application

Tags: android, ios, facebook, apache-flex, accountmanager

Is it possible to retrieve the user account information such as google or facebook accounts using Flex SDK from Android and iOS devices?

There is something like this for Android but for Flex I can`t find anything.

It should be like of list of device accounts and user can choose by himself which of accounts he wants to use and used for Android and iOS devices.

Comment: You mean you want retrieve device settings for Facebook/Google accounts; Or do you want to implement OAuth in your app; so your app can access the accounts?

Comment: I want implement something like OAuth in my app through Google/Facebook/Other accounts (user may choose by himself which account to use) but with the ability to get details of account.

Comment: As part of OAuth you can request access to different account data.  Facebook has dozen's of types of access you can request. My question is; what have you tried? Why didn't it work? What errors did you get?

Comment: Nothing. I just searched information about it.
I know what Facebook had API`s for this purpose.
But I need something that get all accounts from device, not just some what have specific APIs for Flex and retrieve only data from accounts.
It just start of development and I don`t know exactly should be some authorization at all. As I see it will be used just data from device localstorage. That data from accounts I need to build relations between different users and devices.

Comment: I asked if you wanted to retrieve settings for FB/Google accounts and you said you wanted to Implement OAuth. They are two very different requests in my mind. Now I'm unclear exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, if I confused you..
I have specified all details about it and now I can exactly write about my problem.

Comment: So, I need just to get list of accounts that stores on device and get information about user from them.
On android in settings menu there is a list of all accounts uses for different application and I need to get it after user confirmed access to that information. And as I found, iOS can`t provide access to such information.

Currently solution of the problem I see in using different API. User can select the type of account himself that he wants to connect, enter his account details and using the appropriate API I`ll get user data.

Hope now I explain my problem.